# Generate separate private key for ssh on remote server

Tags: ssh, private-key

Does the remote machine that I will be ssh'ing into require it's own private key to be generated so that I can ssh into it from a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is called **Host Key** and it needs to exists before you ssh into the machine. It is used to validate the identity of the server and prevent Man in the Middle Attacks.